# Each deploy increase number of loaded classes

Tags: java, out-of-memory, websphere-7

I'm having an outOfmemory problem in an application deployed in a websphere 7.

I'm using yourKit to try to work it out what's happening and one interesting thing that I could saw is that when I start my application for the first time, it loads around 20k classes and for every time I do another deploy (without restarting websphere) this number increases 2k and the heap size follows this increase.

I'm guessing this is the root problem, but I have no idea how to explain why this is happening.

I tried to list all classes before one deploy and right after another, but this didnt work very well since I could not list all 20k classes (only 10k dont know why). And when I compared the two lists, I found around 600 new classes that were indeed from my application or from dependencies of my application.

I found that most of my applications classes are Enums and implementations of DAO classes.

My application is a Java EE 6 application using Struts and Spring framework.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Classloader leaks are fun! http://frankkieviet.blogspot.com/2006/10/classloader-leaks-dreaded-permgen-space.html

Comment: @damo websphere 7 is fun as hell :)

Comment: Note that there is an inconsistency in your issue description because you are talking about a Java EE 6 application, but WebSphere 7 is a Java EE 5 application server.

Answer (score 1):

`OutOfMemoryError` can be caused when either heap space or permGen space of a JVM is full.

If the problem you're facing is caused by the redeploy of the application, chances are that you're hitting a PermGen OOME. These happen when the application server cannot fully unload the definitions of classes from its memory (memory leak).

This situation is common (at least from my experience) and usually developers just increase the PermGen size of the application server or just bounce the application server to clean the PermGen.

Comment: PermGen is a concept that applies to Sun/Oracle JVMs. On IBM JVMs, things are slightly different. Class objects are simply objects on the heap and don't belong to a distinct generation. The code is loaded into a separate memory area, the size of which is not limited.

Answer (score 0):

That's a typical class loader leak. This may be caused by your application or by a bug in the runtime (i.e. WebSphere or the JRE). Note that there are lots of them in WAS 7, especially in older fix packs.

You may want to consult the following document to get some more insight into the problem:

https://code.google.com/p/arit/wiki/GettingStarted